# Is the Installation file name important?

Tags: windows-10

If downloading a setup.exe file a second time it gets automatically renamed to „setup (1).exe“.
So will starting the installation with it lead to any problem?

Comment: No; It’s a filename of an executable it doesn’t matter

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem - the two names are distinct executable files.
You would only need to remember which is what.

I advise to rename such files while downloading to the name of the product itself.
This makes it much easier to remember.